# How can I change VertexWeights in a Graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in version 10.0.0**

---

I evaluate

```
gt = Graph[{"A" <-> "B", "B" <-> "C", "A" <-> "C", "C" <-> "D"}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
gt = SetProperty[{gt, "B"}, VertexWeight -> 3];
```

I check that the property is set.

```
PropertyValue[{gt, "B"}, VertexWeight]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

Next I evaluate

```
gt = SetProperty[{gt, "A"}, VertexWeight -> 4];
```

and check

```
PropertyValue[{gt, "A"}, VertexWeight]
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

Then I check to confirm the `B` vertex still has the weight I set

```
PropertyValue[{gt, "B"}, VertexWeight]
```

> ```
> 1 (* should be 3 *)
> ```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This clearly shouldn't happen.  It is a bug that I can reproduce in version 9.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this in version 9.0.1 and I think this is a bug. As a workaround, you can set all the vertices' weight at once instead of one-by-one using a different syntax:

```
gt = SetProperty[gt, VertexWeight -> {"A" -> 4, "B" -> 3}];  
VertexList[gt] -> PropertyValue[gt, VertexWeight] // Thread
(* {"A" -> 4, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 1, "D" -> 1} *)
```

Trying to set the `VertexWeight` on any single vertex afterwards will re-set the `VertexWeight` of all other values to 1 (which is incorrect behaviour).

In version 8.0.4 `SetProperty` doesn't work at all with `VertexWeight`: it either returns `$Failed` or simply doesn't have an effect.